# iOS OpenCV: Image matching with ORB leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I'm fairly new to `OpenCV` and I'm trying to match images from the camera feed with provided descriptors for the images that shall be matched. 
However my Objective-C++ code currently crashes with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** which leads me to believe that something has been released or is not present. I just can't quite find the culprit.

I'm using OpenCV 4.1.1 for iOS, Xcode 10.3 and iOS 12.4

I'm using Objective-C++ to speak to OpenCV and and Swift for all UI related things and the rest.

So here's what I've done so far.

I've set up the included `CvVideoCamera` and the camera image is displayed fine inside an `UIImageView`. (since this works fine with simple template matching I'll spare you with that code)

In my `OpenCVWrapper.mm` which is also the CvVideoCamera's delegate I do the following in `processImage:(cv::Mat&)image;`

```
    CV_Assert(!image.empty());
    cv::ORB *orb = cv::ORB::create();
    cv::Mat descriptors, mask;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> points;
    CV_Assert(!orb->empty());
    orb->detectAndCompute(image, mask, points, descriptors);
    cv::DescriptorMatcher *matcher = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create(cv::BFMatcher::BRUTEFORCE) ;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> knnMatches;
    NSArray *targetDescriptors = [[self delegate] descriptors];
    for (SourceDescriptor *source in targetDescriptors) {
        matcher->knnMatch(descriptors, source.mat.mat, knnMatches, 2);
        float ratioThreshold = 0.f;
        NSMutableArray *innerDistances = [@[] mutableCopy];
        for (NSInteger counter = 0; counter < knnMatches.size(); counter++) {
            const cv::DMatch& bestMatch = knnMatches[counter][0];
            const cv::DMatch& betterMatch = knnMatches[counter][1];
            float finalDistance = bestMatch.distance / betterMatch.distance;
            if (finalDistance <= ratioThreshold) {
                [innerDistances addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalDistance]];
            }
        }
        if ([innerDistances count] > 0) {
            NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
            [innerDistances sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highestToLowest]];
            Result *leresult = [[Result alloc] init];
            NSNumber *score = (NSNumber *)[innerDistances objectAtIndex:0];
            [leresult setScore:[score floatValue]];
            [leresult setSourceDescriptor:source];
            [result addObject:leresult];
        }
    }
```

My code however crashes at `orb->detectAndCompute()` with an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

As you can see from the code I'm checking whether the orb or image are empty which isn't the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If any more information needs to be provided I will gladly do so.

Comment: I don't know what exactly may be the issue but I just uploaded samples from our projects that did the same - maybe you would find something helpful there: https://github.com/SparingSoftware/ImageDetect-openCV

Comment: Thanks that helped. The issue was that the cv::ORB has to be created like this cv::Ptr<cv::ORB> *orb = cv::ORB::create(); This is also true for the DescriptionMatcher. However the CV_ASSERT fails but the code works. If you put your comment as an Answer I'll check it as correct :)